# belongsTo Or hasOne Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables, Users and Profile_Education. Users data is coming from an auth0/login form, and Profile_Education is coming from an API using node.js/express. I want Profile_education to have a foreign key to track data and display it in a profile Based on the user who logs in.

In my project, should I use belongsTo or hasOne, or should I use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both of them but use it where it suitable , as per the **[DOC](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto)** :

> When information about association is present in source model we can
>   use belongsTo. In this case Player is suitable for belongsTo because
>   it has teamId column.
>
> ```
> Player.belongsTo(Team)  // `teamId` will be added on Player / Source model
> ```
>
> When information about association is present in target model we can
>   use hasOne. In this case Coach is suitable for hasOne because Team
>   model store information about its Coach as coachId field.
>
> ```
> Coach.hasOne(Team)  // `coachId` will be added on Team / Target model
> ```

I think this will clear all your doubts ,